# defining a function handle matlab 6.5

Tags: matlab, function, syntax

I'm stuck with a `fmincon` problem because I don't know how to declare my objective function in Matlab 6.5. I tried to declare my objective function as a separate m.file called `parameterfun`

```
function y=parameterfun(X,A,b)
y=sum((A*X(:)-b).^2);
```

Then I tried to call that function in the following routine

```
L=50e3;
n=5;
zi=linspace(0,L,n);
alpha=zi./L;
A=[alpha.^(5/3); alpha.^(5/6).*(1-alpha).^(5/6)]

lambda=1e-6;
k=2*pi/lambda;
Cn2=1e-16;

r0sw=(0.423*k^2*Cn2*3/8*L)^(-3/5);
rytov=0.1241*Cn2*k^(7/6)*L^(11/6);
b=[r0sw; rytov];

x0=(n/3*r0sw*ones(n,1)).^(-5/3); %%starting guess
fun=@parameterfun(X,A,b);
lb=zeros(n,1);
ub=0.1/1.33*(k*L)^(5/6)./A(2,:);
ub(A(2,:)==0)=50^(-5/3);
X = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)
```

I really don't know how to declare and call my objective function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what **exactly** is the error you are getting? you need to post this to get better answers.

Comment: You need anonymous functions. Have a look here http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: I got the message: ??? Error: File: C:\MATLAB6p5\work\carolingio.m Line: 24 Column: 18
Missing operator, comma, or semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining `fun` correctly. Please try

```
fun = @(X) parameterfun(X,A,b);
```

This way you define a function handle `fun` *that accepts a single input argument `x`* and returns `parameterfun(X,A,b)`.
See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) for more information.

Comment: Still don't working I got the message: ??? Error: File: C:\MATLAB6p5\work\carolingio.m Line: 24 Column: 6
"identifier" expected, "(" found.

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff and what does line 24 look like? How do you expect anyone to solve your problem without providing **all** the relevant information in a **clear** manner?

Comment: Sorry, my program is exactly as posted but I forgot to clean some comments in top of it, for that reason line 24 is: fun=@(x) parameterfun(X,A,b)

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff if you type `>> doc function_handle` in your command window, what do you get?

Comment: It redirects me to the help documentation. Using the ver command tells me that  I have Optimization Toolbox Version 2.2 (R13). I guess the problem has to do with the vector X and x0.

Comment: if you only type `fun = @(X) parameterfun(X,A,b);` in the command line, do you get any error? @CarolinaRickenstorff

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff please note that `X` must be a capital both in the parenthesis and in the argument list (I had a typo in an earlier version).

Comment: It shows me: fun = @(X) parameterfun(X,A,b);
           |
Error: "identifier" expected, "(" found.

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff and what happens if you type `str2func('@(X) parameterfun(X,A,b)')` in the command line?

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff it's very odd. can you try and open a new instance of Matlab and only type `fun = @(X) parameterfun(X,A,b);` in the command line?

Comment: Hello, I type: str2func('@(X) parameterfun(X,A,b)') and got: ??? Error using ==> str2func
Invalid function name '@(X) parameterfun(X,A,b)'. With new instance do you refer to a new m.file?

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff by "new instance" I mean open a new Matlab, not an m-file.

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff: This answer is not working because your MATLAB Version is to old to support function handles.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions have been introduced in MATLAB 7 / R14. You are using Matlab 6.5 / R13 which does not support anonymous functions. In newer MATLAB versions the suggestion from Shai would be the solution:

```
fun = @(X) parameterfun(X,A,b);
```

For old MATLAB versions you have to use inline instead

```
fun=inline('parameterfun(X,A,b)','X')
```